# Idle event on mouse move - how to create loop?

Tags: javascript, loops

Im trying to create this kind of code on my website:
When user is idle div "#news-main-page" have to fade in and fade out every 15 seconds.

But when user moves mouse I want function to break.

When user break function when news-main-page is visible it stays visible, 
when user break function when news-main-page is hidden it stays hidden.

How to achieve this?

Right now it work like this if user will start moving mouse after sometime idle, function still execute

Below is my code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    idleTimer = null;
    idleState = false;
    idleWait = 15000;
    (function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('*').bind('mousemove keydown scroll', function () {

            clearTimeout(idleTimer);

            if (idleState == true) { 
                // Reactivated event
            }

            idleState = false;

            idleTimer = setTimeout(function () { 
                // Idle Event
                $('#news-main-page').removeClass('d-none');
                $("#news-main-page").delay(15000).fadeOut(); 
                $("#news-main-page").delay(15000).fadeIn(); 
                $("#news-main-page").delay(15000).fadeOut(); 

                idleState = true; }, idleWait);
            });

            $("body").trigger("mousemove");
        });
    }) (jQuery)
});
```

Comment: As an aside. You have a ready handler inside another ready handler. This is not necessary

Answer (score 1):

Just call .stop() on news-main-page

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
      var myFunc = 
         function () {

        clearTimeout(idleTimer);

        if (idleState == true) { 
            // Reactivated event
        }

        idleState = false;

        idleTimer = setTimeout(function () { 
            // Idle Event
            $('#news-main-page').removeClass('d-none');
            $("#news-main-page").delay(15000).fadeOut(); 
            $("#news-main-page").delay(15000).fadeIn(); 
            $("#news-main-page").delay(15000).fadeOut(); 

            idleState = true; }, idleWait);
        });

        $("body").mouseMove(function() {
          $('*').unbind('mousemove keydown scroll',myFunc);
          $("#news-main-page").stop();
        });
    });
    $('*').bind('mousemove keydown scroll',myFunc);
}) (jQuery)
```

Comment: Yeah, it's working. Now when I start moving the script stops. However when mouse is idle script runs again. How to kill this script with first move of mouse?

Comment: @David the best way to "kill this script with first move of mouse" is to unbind it. Put the outer function in a variable, and then use unbind before where you have stop. Does that work for you or do you need me to update my answer to show what I'm saying explicitly

Comment: Could you please update your answer? Im trying to unbind it but it dont work as I expect

Comment: @David I have updated my answer. Look for where I am calling unbind

Comment: Still not working. Here's my fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/2Lrxehz8/ . When I add it to my website first I get error about unexptected ")" and after I fixed it about myFunc is undefinded. After I try to fixed it its still not working